# Image get distorted after being sent via broswer

Tags: images, browser, image-manipulation

Hello I am using parrot OS, and My problem is whenever i capture the screenshot at my linux machine and try to send it via browser or web.whatsapp. The image get's distorted. [Please Have a look at this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOXa6.jpg).

Comment: You may want to add some detail. Do you get the distortion when making the screenshot, or only when you send it? How do you make the screenshot?

Comment: I only get when i send it via Broswer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, The issue was with browser. the easy fix is to turn off `"Use hardware acceleration when available"` feature in your browser and it will be fixed